# Подсчет числа пар равных элементов

Tags: c++

Дан массив чисел. Посчитайте, сколько в нем пар элементов, равных друг другу. Считается, что любые два элемента, равные друг другу образуют одну пару, которую необходимо посчитать. Не пойму, как реализовать через for
Мои мысли - надо цикл в цикле делать и там сравнивать, но вообще сообразить не могу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы реализовал как-то так:

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
                summa++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: =) По идее, cin можно засунуть внутрь следующего for и упростить всё, пытаюсь разобраться в другой задаче, разберусь - отпишу)